# How to execute same job in a same time concurrently

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

I have already created job and i need to execute job in about 15 time within 10 times nearly. created job spend 4 min finish that steps. how to do this?

Comment: You want to run jobs in parallel?

Comment: yes sir i want run same job parallel in same time

Comment: The short answer is you can't. So now is the time to step back and re-envision your goal. You might be able to add the "parallelization" logic inside the job - but that is doubtful. And I will guess that you probably don't know if your logic would be successful when run as parallel processes - so this might not work at all. Without any detail, it is impossible to suggest more.

Comment: thanks have any idea do this?